# how to launch multiple fragments from a parent fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a parent fragment and when i click in a button to open  first fragment then click in button in first fragment to open a second fragment and from second fragment to third fragment and so on ....

i succeeded to do that but the application  becomes very slow after launching multiple fragments

this is the code i used to launch any fragment

```
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {


            Fragment newFragment = new newFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction =  
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(fragmentContainer.getId(), newFragment);

             transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code seems ok, maybe look at they layouts, do you have lots of LinearLayout or RelativeLayout in cascade for exemple ?

Comment: i used 2 RelativeLayout  in xml file for each fragment @An-droid

Comment: Relative layout should be used carefully, they are heavy on memory. Also, popping several fragments one on another without cleaning them, i think it's normal that things begin to slow down

Comment: how to clean on after open another , i used replace() function ? @An-droid

Comment: You should clean your fragments views, context, activities references in onDestroyView() to avoid memory leaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i should use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling **`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`** then you must use **`getSupportFragmentManager()`**.

> public FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager ()
>
> Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
>   with this activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your new fragments are not transparent, I think you should check the overdraw of layouts.
2. The replace() needs to recreate the instance and reload data, maybe add() and hide() can help you.